# Why is this error: reference to ‘statusBar’ is ambiguous.. coming? Is this a bug?

Tags: c++, qt4, ambiguous

I created a QMainWindow using QT Designer.
As we know, it has statusBar by default.

By default, QT Designer gave its objectname as "statusBar".
Now, when I tried to call like:-

```
statusBar()->showMessage(tr("File successfully loaded."), 3000);
```

as we have a function with prototype: QStatusBar * QMainWindow::statusBar () const

The Compiler shows the error:-

> error: reference to ‘statusBar’ is ambiguous.
>
> error: candidates are: QStatusBar* Ui_MainWindow::statusBar
>
> error: QStatusBar*QMainWindow::statusBar() const

Actually, i was following a book "The Art of Building Qt Applications by DANIEL MOLKENTIN". And I am compiling the same code given in book.

Above code is in mainwindows.cpp and i have included "mainwindow.h" & "ui_mainwindow.h" in it...

Is this a bug in QT4??

Comment: You have a member *variable* names `statusBar` and a method names `statusBar`. The compiler doesn't know which one to use. However, both reside in different classes: `Ui_MainWindow` and `QMainWindow`. I wonder what is the relationship between these classes? If one is inheriting from the other, how come there's no hame hiding? If they are unrelated, how come there's a conflict? Are you sure you haven't added something "strange" from yourself? Multiple inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask for a specific version of the method statusBar():

```
Ui_MainWindow::statusBar()->showMessage(tr("File successfully loaded."), 3000);
```

Comment: No that will throw an error.. There is no function named statusBar in Ui_MainWindow..
Anyways, i think you wrote it in a hurry. It should be QMainWindow::statusBar().....

But, the main agenda was, is it a BUG?

Comment: That's not what the error above (in your question) says. Yes it is a BUG in __Your__ code (or the book). But without further context (like the code) it is imposable to narrow it down further.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that QMainWindow extends Ui_MainWindow, which also defines the statusBar method.

Probably this wasn't the case in previous versions of QT.

Comment: I am a newbie for GUI stuff with just knowledge of basic C++. 
so have I found a bug?

Comment: No this is normal behaviour and not a bug. Since there are two definitions of statusBar, you need to explicitly select one.

Answer (score 1):

I also read that book and had the same problem. The decision is:

1. invoke the method `QMainWindow::statusBar()` 
   `QMainWindow::statusBar()->showMessage(tr("File successfully loaded."), 3000);`
2. or use a pointer `*statusBar` from `Ui_MainWindow` 
   `Ui_MainWindow::statusBar->showMessage(tr("File successfully loaded."), 3000);`